Synchronous image loading warning in React Native - How to fix using URLSession?
I'm encountering a warning in Xcode's log when testing my React Native app:

Synchronous URL loading of http://localhost:8081/assets/assets/image/ImageUser.png?platform=ios&hash=c7acd2e8e0e1768b55d4ee625fb73ffb should not occur on this application's main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession.

My code:
import {Image} from 'react-native'

const Images = {
  user: require('../image/ImageUser.png'),
}

const AppImage = () => {
  <Image source={Images.user} />
}

My app displays the image normally despite the warning.
How can I resolve this warning?

You can try to write in DispatchQueue.main.async { // image loading } block

@Shivbaba'sson But my app is React-Native, not write by Swift native
